# Page Builder does not appear in Magento 2

Tags: cms-pages, page-builder

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
```

In:

- Stores > Settings > Configuration - in the left panel under General > Content Management > Advanced Content Tools - Enable Page Builder is set to **Yes**

When adding a new CMS Page, **it does not appear at all**:

```
Content > Pages > Add New Page

> I have selected Enable Page = Yes 
Assigned a Page title and Content Heading
```

Directly underneath the Content heading is a button 'Edit with Page Builder' and a graphic of a rectangle with a hand and an arrow underneath which it says:

Drag Row, Columns, Tabs, Block, Dynamic Block or HTML Code here

[image]

*When I click on the Edit with Page Builder button - I get the following page.* There is absolutely **NO way possible to open any kind of a window here to enter text whatsoever:**

[image]

**How do I actually paste code or text into the Page?**

Comment: Have you tried dragging sections from left tab to the main screen? Try dragging elements like "Text" from left section to the main screen and after that you should be able to edit.

Comment: @amitshree That worked - thank you! If you want to type that up as an answer - I will select it as the correct answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once we open any page to edit using page builder it doesn't give a way to enter any text by default.

If you want to add some content to the page, you need to select the elements from left navigation bar based on your requirement of the page design, drag it to the content section and then you should be able to add the content.

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer attached screenshot
Can’t use MAGENTO page builder to edit home page theme of Porto theme - is it an error with my magento installation ?
https://share.getcloudapp.com/X6uRw9LD

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the cog, the wheel--that should open up the edit window